# Letter count program

Tags: python

In my letter counting function, when is use this code

```
 from collections import Counter
import string
pickedletter= ()
count = 0
word = ()


def count_letters(word):
    global count
    wordsList = word.split()
    for words in wordsList:
        if words == pickedletter:
            count = count+1
    return count

word = input("what do you want to type? ")
pickedletter = input("what letter do you want to pick? ")
print (count_letters(word))
```

I get that the amount of a certain letter is 0, no matter what. For example, here is what I got in the command prompt

```
what do you want to type? rht
what letter do you want to pick? r
0
>>>
```

How would you fix this to get how many times a letter appears in a string?

Comment: How would a word (aside from `'a'` or `'I'`) ever be equal to a letter? Also, why import `Counter` then *never use it*?!

Comment: May I ask why you initialize `word`, and why `count` has to be a `global`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Especially since `Counter` makes this program a one-liner that's nearly impossible to get wrong… But for your main question: at least [`'o'`](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/O#English) and [`'y'`](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Y#English) are words (archaic/poetic vocative particle, and y-shaped object, respectively). :P

Comment: @jonrsharpe There r more, k? y can't u c them? b n educated person n make t.

Comment: @StefanPochmann: nothing compares 2 u.

Comment: @abarnert No problem I'll just `class StefanPochmann: def __gt__(self, other): return True`

Comment: @StefanPochmann: I always thought Prince was saying that his girlfriend was not fully ordered, not that she was infinite. He should start writing his songs in code instead of English to avoid these ambiguities.

Answer (score 3):

There's a method that already counts number of occurrences of a character. For case insensitive, use String.lower()

```
print (word.count(pickedletter))
```

Comment: Not if he wants the character count, regardless of the case.

Comment: If he wants case insensitivity, he can use `word.lower()` and `pickedletter.lower()`.

Comment: Or `unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', word).casefold()`, if he wants it to work in every language and script in the world instead of just English.

Answer (score 0):

To count the *exact* character, you can use the builtin [`count` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.count).

```
>>> mystring = "This is a test."
>>> mystring.count("t")
2
```

If you want to count *regardless of the case*, you can use the [`str.lower` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower).

```
>>> mystring = "This is a test."
>>> mystring.lower().count("t")
3
```

You have to `lower` the string, because the character codes for `T` and `t` are not the same. They are 84 and 116, respectively.

In your function, it would look like this:

```
def count_letters(word):
    return word.count(pickedletter)
```

Or

```
def count_letters(word):
    return word.lower().count(pickedletter)
```

**EDIT** (thanks to abarnert)

If you intend to use this in non-English languages, you should use the [`casefold` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.casefold) instead. However, this is only available in Python 3.

```
>>> mystring = "This is a test."
>>> mystring.casefold().count("t")
3
```

Comment: `lower` doesn't work for many non-English languages, so you really should use `casefold`, and ideally normalize to NFKD as well.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you've imported `Counter`, the easiest way to do what you want is:

```
from collections import Counter

word = input('What do you want to type? ')
bag = Counter(word)
pickedLetter = input('What letter do you want to pick? ')
print(bag.get(pickedLetter, 0))
```

Comment: You don't need `get` with `Counter`; it already defaults to 0 for missing keys.

Comment: Good to know.  I primarily use dictionaries and I thought the same rules applied to counters.